# Почему фейлится запрос в retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Делаю запрос на сервер с помощью rertofit2. Приходит ответ, а потом фейлится (onFailure).

Интерфейс

```
public interface TheOwmApi {

@GET("forecast" )
Call<Data> getData(@Query("q") String cityName, @Query("APPID") String appId, @Query("units") String metric, @Query("lang") String lang);
```

}

```
public class App extends Application {

private static TheOwmApi sTheOwmApi;
private Retrofit retrofit;
private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Interceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            .setLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);

    okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    sTheOwmApi = retrofit.create(TheOwmApi.class);
}

public static TheOwmApi getApi() {
    return sTheOwmApi;
}
```

}

Сам запрос

```
 App.getApi().getData(getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_NAME"), API_KEY, "metric", "ru").enqueue(new Callback<Data>() {
        public void onResponse(Call<Data> call, Response<Data> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Status Code = " + response.code());

                mData = response.body();
                temp.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(mData.getList().get(0).getMain().getTemp())));
                mTodayAdapter.changeDataSet(mData.getList());
            } else {
                try {
                    Log.d("TAG", response.errorBody().string());
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    Log.d("TAG", ioe.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
            horRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Data> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("TAG", "FAIL");
        }

    });
```

Comment: И что же в `onFailure` в `t` написано? Какое исключение?

Comment: А что в `Throwable t`-то приходит, это же самое важное?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja я не знаю, что необходимо прописать.

Comment: `t.getMessage()` в лог надо вывести и почитать.